# Impedance Matching for Helical Antenna

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching, characteristic-impedance

I'm building a helical antenna at 1.7 GHz from scratch. Theory says that its characteristic impedance is 140 Ohm. The RF transmission line is 50 Ohm so there has to be an impedance transformer in between. What is the proposed  custom implementation of such a transformer? I have come across the LC circuit as a possible transformer, but is it enough for 5 MHz of bandwidth that i require from the antenna? What's the simplest transformer that will do the job for me?

Thank you for your time

Comment: at 1.7 GHz, 5 MHz is really not that much bandwidth – so a simple LC circuit really can't be too selective there.

Answer (score 1):

Hope that I am not oversimplifying your problem.

I am not fully versed on this antenna, but to me, an impedance of 140Ohms seemed a little off for anything that I have laid out for 1.7GHz. (Pardon my ignorance for your analysis, but just in case.)  There are some impedance transformers for 1.7 GHz in Minicircuits, but I have the sense that those frequencies are prohibitively high for them. Depending on your output power, an LC impedance matching network or a microstrip matching network would work better. You might consult to Pozar for textbook examples. For broadband applications, I have used Richard Li's book for intuitive broadband matching tricks, there might be some use in checking that book also.

Comment: There are impedance transformers that are actual transformers (two coils coupled to each other) I refer to them in *impedance transformers for 1.7 GHz in Minicircuits*

Answer (score 1):

The classic impedance transformer is a \$\frac{\lambda}{4}\$ length of transmission line, of the geometric mean impedance. In this case, sqrt(50*140) = 83 ohms.

75 ohms is quite close, and 140 ohms through a \$\frac{\lambda}{4}\$ of 75 ohms comes out to be 40 ohms. Not perfect, but it improves the return loss from  -6.5dB directly to -19dB through the transformer. May be good enough for you.

If not, it does mean you have a much less extreme impedance ratio to tidy up with an L and a C.

Answer (score 1):

I see this is nearly three years old, but this might help people who visit later.

Having done this myself some time ago, for Rx only (MetWxSat) as I am assuming the OP is also intending to do, my solution was to recalculate the helix dimensions for a nominal impedance of 150 ohms, build three of them, mount them as an array and connect them directly in parallel. the feedpoint is then at 50 ohms.

The impedance of a monofilar helical antenna in axial mode is approximately given by 140c/lambda (c= circumference, lambda=wavelength at the frequency of operation)

Therefore the 140 ohms impedance quoted by the OP is valid only for c=lambda.

increasing  the circumference (and turns pitch, so therefore also the length) by approximately 7% will drop the target frequency to approximately 1586MHz and raise the impedance to 150 ohms at 1700MHz

The axial mode helical antenna is a travelling-wave type antenna and therefore essentially non-resonant, and broadband - usable on frequencies 3/4 to 4/3 of the target frequency. Any loss of efficiency incurred by this change will therefore be negligible.

There are so many resources online to verify this that I decline to give one, and instead will allow Google to be your friend.